# Where does the demo end on xbox

Tags: xbox-360, terraria-console

When does the demo of terraria end on Xbox? I'm not sure exactly but I summoned the Eye of Chutulu and I was about to hit it and the game froze then sent me to the dashboard. If this is where the demo ends why don't they tell you?

Answer (score 2):

The Terraria demo appears to be fully functional, with a couple of limitations:

- The world is much smaller (Some people are saying it's [1/10 of the small world](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/683105-terraria/65821080))
- There's no character/progression saving

As for what happened to you, I'm guessing you were unlucky and the game crashed. There are a few people reporting similar experiences with the full game on the Terraria forums:

http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/game-crash.96733/